# std::out_of_range exception is not thrown

Tags: c++, exception, std, stdvector

```
   // The following code works fine, throwing a std::out_of_range exception:
    
    std::vector<double> vd{ 1.5 };
    
        try {
            int i{ -1 };
            double d = vd.at(i); // exception is thrown
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range& re) {
            std::cout << "Exception is " << re.what() << std::endl; // invalid vector subscript
        }
```

If I access vector elements in a for loop with an invalid index, no `std::exception` is thrown although I use `.at()`. Why is the `std::out_of_range` exception not thrown?

```
// in a for loop, this does not throw the exception!

std::vector<double> vd{ 1.5 };

    try {
        for (int i = -1; i < vd.size(); ++i) 
            double d = vd.at(i); // exception is not thrown. Why?

    }
    catch (std::out_of_range& re) {
        std::cout << "Exception is " << re.what() << std::endl; // exception is not thrown
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the loop does not execute. `-1 < vd.size()` is false.

`size()` returns an **unsigned** value. So before comparing the two numbers `-1` is converted into an unsigned value. This conversion is done modulo the largest `unsigned` value plus one, which means that `-1` is converted to the largest possible `unsigned` value. That is then compared with the size of your vector, and that comparison is always false.

Signed/unsigned comparsions are problematic for this reason. Although well defined, they don't work in the mathematically expected way if the signed value is negative. Your compiler should warn you about this problem.

Comment: So thanks to your impressive explanation "for (int i = -1; i < static_cast<int>(vd.size()); ++i)" would produce the exception. Wonderful, thank you very much.

Comment: @ByronB Yes it would. Worth noting that the same signed to unsigned conversion is happening when you call `at` since that takes an unsigned argument.

Comment: @ByronB Yes, vector indexes are unsigned, so a too low index is impossible. But (unless your vector is absolutely massive) the signed to unsigned conversion rules ensure that a negative index is always too big.

Comment: @ByronB Personal opinion but I think the counter intuitive results arising from mixing signed and unsigned values are not worth it. The language would have been better without any unsigned data types. It's only in very specialist situations that unsigned types are required, but signifcant bugs arise from careless mixing of signed and unsigned types. This seems to be a minority view however.

Comment: So you say the std::out_of_range exception when using.at(-1) is not thrown because of a too low index value but because of a too high index value of for example 4294967295 on a 32 bit machine with size_t = 4 byte), after the conversion of int { -1 } to the unsigned int of size_t because of at(). Beautiful, thank you so very much for this great insight.